# What does this icon in the Visual Studio 2017 status bar mean?

Tags: visual-studio

I see these icons in the status bar:

[image: status bar]

There are no tooltips. The icons are animated.
I know [image: icon2] means the building process. But what is [image: icon1] ? It appears sometimes sporadically and I can't figure out what does it mean.

Comment: In here https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=35825 you can download the full list of icons appearing in visual studio and their explanations. 2017 is missing though,

Comment: @k_kaz do you imply I have to download a 2.9 Gb image library in order to reveal this particular icon meaning?

Comment: sorry i don't know the explanation, maybe this icon appears in previous versions...

Answer (score 2):

I think it represents background tasks.  If you click the icon to the far left it will show you what it’s doing.  In my case I’m restoring NPM packages, so I’ll wait.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is displayed when NuGet or NPM packages are being installed.